# ошибка при настройке проксирования с nginx на apache

Tags: apache, nginx

При настройке проксирования с nginx на apache в директиве location / { }
при передачи заголовка через proxy_set_header Host $host;
Выходит ошибка "Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Linux 4.17.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Jul 28 09:33:09 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

Comment: Вроде нашел решение заменил proxy_set_header Host $host;  на add_header HOST $host;  Т.е. мы данный заголовок не проксируем а отдаем сразу в браузер клиенту на уровне nginx  (решение было отсюда взято https://serverfault.com/questions/808990/proxy-set-header-not-working  )
Может кто подсказать, это верное решение?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    ....
}
```

Comment: proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr; даная директива стоятала,
proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;  - та же ошибка